# Update Row By Row number

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am having a table with one column only

```
id
--
1
2
3
5
5
```

I want to update the value of 4 th row  to "4"
so required output is :

```
id
--
1
2
3
4
5
```

how can i achieve this

Comment: What else is in your table?  Is there something that can uniquely identify the row you want to change?

Comment: nothing in that table..only one column

Comment: @All sorry i did not know that we can use CTE in Update query

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT ID, RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID ASC)
    FROM dbo.TableName
)
UPDATE CTE SET ID = RN
WHERE ID <> RN
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a0801/3/0)</kbd>

That will update all "incorrect" ID's according to their row number that is determined by the order.